# Problem with wallpaper app

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have a wallpaper app and it seems to work fine but... when i open the app in eclipse... the app icon appears as the first image in the wallpaper. I cannot figure out what is happening. can someone help.

also the scrolling seemed to have slowed down after i added more images (40)..any suggestions. what is the recommended file size the files papers should be. I know the dimensions but what about the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution isn't relevant if you already know the dimensions (if I'm understanding you correctly). For the Droid, you need 960 x 854 pixel images. When I hear resolution, I think dpi/ppi.

As far as the app icon appearing in the list...you should post some code as to how you're listing the images. Are you just populating them from the @drawables folder? That's where your app icon is stored, too.